# How to loop over a map and return value if it matches with a value from a list in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a map with variable names of a subnet and their ids
eg:

```
subnet_id = {
             subnet-a="XXXX/subnet-a",
             subnet-b="XXXX/subnet-b",
             subnet-c="XXXX/subnet-c"
}
```

I have a list variable(subnet_variable_name) with the variable names of subnets (which is a value inside a map variable:network_rule)
eg:

```
network_rule = {
  rule1 = {    
    subnet_variable_name = ["subnet-a","subnet-b"]
    rule = []
  }
}
```

How do I loop through subnet_id and return the values where the key matches with values in list subnet_variable_name ? I tried using the below for function but it is throwing an error.

```
resource "xxx" "xxx"{  
for_each                  = var.network_rule
subnet_ids = {for value in each.value["subnet_variable_name"]: value => lookup(var.subnet_id, value, null)}
}
```

Error :

```
    Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│    7:   subnet_ids = {for value in each.value["subnet_variable_name"]: value => lookup(var.subnet_id, value, null)}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value["subnet_variable_name"] is list of string with 1 element
│     │ var.subnet_id is map of string with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": set of string required.
```

Edit: the result I want is for subnet_ids to be assigned ["XXXX/subnet-a","XXXX/subnet-b"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition with [`contains`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/contains) and [`keys`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/keys) functions:

```
resource "xxx" "xxx" {
  for_each    = var.network_rule
  subnet_ids  = [
    for subnet in each.value.subnet_variable_name: subnet if contains(keys(var.subnet_id), subnet)
  ]
}
```

Update:

If you want the value of the `subnet_id` instead of the key, you can do the following:

```
resource "xxx" "xxx" {
  for_each    = var.network_rule
  subnet_ids  = [
    for subnet in each.value.subnet_variable_name: var.subnet_id[subnet] if contains(keys(var.subnet_id), subnet)
  ]
}
```

Comment: This returns the variable name for the subnet(which is a value inside network_rule) .  I want just value returned from subnet_id . For this scenario I want it to return ["XXXX/subnet-a", "XXXX/subnet-b"]

Comment: Updated my answer. Next time please be specific what you would want to be the expected output.

Comment: Thank you . This is my first time posting a question . I will be more specific next time onwards.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I hope I could help.

Comment: Yes , we error got resolved. Thanks!